# How to perform full check of ext4 file system structure?

Tags: debian, partition, fsck

I have 2TB ext4 partition with half million files on it.
I want to check whether this partition contains any errors or not.
I don't want to search for bad blocks, only logical structure should be checked.

I have unmounted the partition and run `fsck /dev/sda2`, but fsck returns immediately with exit code 0 without actually checking whole file system.
I'm expecting full partition check would take hours to complete.
I have read `man fsck` but did not find an option for "thorough testing".

I'm afraid my partition may have some sectors accidentally overwritten by garbage data.
My HDD was previously connected to another OS, and ext4 partition may get harmed by wrong behavior of that OS.
That's why I want to be sure the whole tree structure is completely correct.

In other words, I want to perform a check similar to what utility `chkdsk.exe` does on Windows.
What should I use on Debian to completely check ext4 file system?

Comment: @SatoKatsura - Thanks!  I just wonder why `e2fsck -f` check is so fast - it takes only several seconds?  It's amazing compared to Windows behavior (it takes hours).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As mentioned by [Satō Katsura](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117516/sato-katsura), run `e2fsck` in "force" mode:

```
e2fsck -f /dev/sda2
```

This will force a check even if the system thinks the file system is clean. The "verbose" option is helpful too:

```
e2fsck -vf /dev/sda2
```

As a side-note, and not applicable in your case, but if you use LVM for your storage you can use the neat little [`lvcheck`](https://github.com/BryanKadzban/lvcheck) tool to run an "offline" file system check on a mounted file system (it uses an LVM snapshot and updates the file system metadata if the check doesn't find any errors).

Answer (score 11):

Also, you could add the `-y` flag to avoid answering questions.

[From the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck):

> `-y`   assume an answer of `yes` to all questions; allows `e2fsck` to be used non-interactively.

So extending the answer (since I cannot comment yet) from [@Sato](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117516/sato-katsura) - you could run:

```
e2fsck -vfy /dev/sda2
```

Comment: That can be risky though, because you don't know in advance what you may get asked, and forcing a yes answer to everything could in the worst case lead to loss of otherwise recoverable data.

Comment: @Alex, Interesting! Could you give an example of a situation where `-y` can cause "loss of otherwise recoverable data"?

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver Nothing concrete, no. But I've had a borked filesystem in the past where my internet searches led me to reading forum posts where I found examples of people running fsck (or similar) who let it do fixes actually caused more corruption. Anything tool that "automatically fixes" something can, under the right circumstances, fix things incorrectly if the (meta)data corruption is bad enough.

Answer (score 5):

During boot a linux system will check the [fstab](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38125/htg-explains-what-is-the-linux-fstab-and-how-does-it-work/) or the existence of a file named `forcefsck` in the root of the device. if the last number on the mount line in fstab is `0` the device will be checked during boot. To create the file `forcefsck` use these commands.

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
sudo reboot
```

With this file at the root a volume the same will be checked during (re)boot irrespective of what is in fstab.

The downside is that during fsck the system is unavailable and will *not* respond to remote requests over for instance ssh.

(EDIT according to @kusalananda comments)

Comment: Although possibly correct, this answer lacks any form of explanation. Could you possibly describe what your commands do, what the consequence of them would be, and where the user in the question might read more about this (where there might have learnt this if they had found the correct manual, etc.)?

Comment: This answer is as close to self-explanatory as two commands could be. 99.9% of the time I would appreciate more explanation, but this time, it's clear enough not to need it. Rare, but it happens.

Comment: Really?  Doesn't seem clear to me.  I'm guessing that on reboot, if the directory forcefsck exists on root, a check desk will be run.  Not sure.  Now to google it and confirm, and provide a reference.

Comment: Ok, so obviously, it's a file that is created, not a directory (there's now 'mkdir').  And indeed, it would seem to work:  https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-force-fsck-to-check-filesystem-after-system-reboot-on-linux

Comment: This would work but also halt booting until the check is finished. For a 2TB disk this might take the system off-line for a long time.

Comment: This flag is interpreted by the sysvinit startup script [mountall.conf](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/main/amd64/mountall/2.53/file/etc/init/mountall.conf); it won't work on systemd-based distros.

Comment: In fstab, "0 means that fsck will not check the filesystem."
https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/etc-fstab

Answer (score 2):

You can also check live file systems in read-only mode with this:

```
e2fsck -vfn /dev/sda2
```

Comment: From e2fsck help: "However, even if it is safe to do so, the results printed by e2fsck are not valid if the filesystem is mounted." Not sure what the purpose is of such as check... :/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [tune2fs](https://landoflinux.com/linux_tune2fs_command.html) for this purpose, for example the following command will check the disk after 2 months or 100 mounts:

```
tune2fs -c 100 -i 2m /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Not on android.

Comment: @user2284570 question was about debian, not android ;-)